# Pass data to tab fragments on onPostExecute complete

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-asynctask, android-nested-fragment

I am trying to pass an ArrayList to `child tab fragment` from `main fragment`. The ArrayList is populated from the Asynctask task in the main fragment. I am using the ArrayList in child fragment to show the `ListView`. However, I am getting empty ListView.
The child fragment is created before the Asynctask completion.

I tried the following code:

My HomeFragment (i.e. MainFragment)

```
public class HomeFragment extends MainFragment {

private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
protected ArrayList<ModelClass> models= new ArrayList<ModelClass> ();


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mTabHost = new FragmentTabHost(getActivity());
    mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(),
            R.layout.newcourse_screen);

    Bundle arg1 = new Bundle();
    arg1.putInt("Arg for Frag1", 1);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator("Tab1"),
            CourseHomeFragment.class, arg1);

    Bundle arg2 = new Bundle();
    arg2.putInt("Arg for Frag2", 2);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator("Tab2"),
            Fragment2.class, arg2);

    Bundle arg3 = new Bundle();
    arg2.putInt("Arg for Frag3", 3);
    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab3").setIndicator("Tab3"),
            Fragment3.class, arg3);

    for (int i = 0; i < mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
        mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_selector);
        mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().height = pixels;
        TextView tv = (TextView) mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
                .findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        tv.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
        tv.setSingleLine(true);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#898989"));
    }
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(mTabHost.getCurrentTab())
            .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_selector);
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(mTabHost.getCurrentTab())
            .getLayoutParams().height = pixels;

    TextView tv = (TextView) mTabHost.getTabWidget()
            .getChildAt(mTabHost.getCurrentTab())
            .findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    tv.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
    tv.setSingleLine(true);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
                mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
                        .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_selector);
                mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().height = pixels;

                TextView tv = (TextView) mTabHost.getTabWidget()
                        .getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
                tv.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
                tv.setSingleLine(true);
                tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#898989"));
            }
            mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(mTabHost.getCurrentTab())
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_selector);
            mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(mTabHost.getCurrentTab())
                    .getLayoutParams().height = pixels;

            TextView tv = (TextView) mTabHost.getTabWidget()
                    .getChildAt(mTabHost.getCurrentTab())
                    .findViewById(android.R.id.title);
            tv.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
            tv.setSingleLine(true);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        }
    });

    return mTabHost;
}

    @Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    new GetCourses().execute("");

}

private class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // Performing operation and updating the Arraylist models //

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        AppData.showSpinnerDialog(getActivity(), false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        AppData.dismisssSpinnerDialog();
    }
}
}
```

My CouseHomeFragment (i.e. ChildTabFragment)

```
public class CourseHomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayList<CurriculumModel> curriculum = new ArrayList<CurriculumModel>();
ListView lview;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newcourse_screen, container, false);
    lview = (ListView) V.findViewById(R.id.listView_course);

    ((PullToRefreshListView) lview)
            .setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                    // Do work to refresh the list here.
                    // new GetCourses().execute("");
                    ((PullToRefreshListView) lview).onRefreshComplete();
                }
            });

    CourseRowAdapter mAdapter = new CourseRowAdapter(getActivity(),
            models, true);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lview.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    return V;
}
}
```

CourseRowAdapter

```
public class CourseRowAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public Activity context;
private ArrayList<CurriculumModel> curriculumItems;
private TypedArray courseIcons;
boolean status;

public CourseRowAdapter(Activity context,
        ArrayList<CurriculumModel> curriculumItems, boolean status) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.curriculumItems = curriculumItems;
    this.status = status;
    courseIcons = context.getResources().obtainTypedArray(
            R.array.course_icons);

}



public void setCurriculumItems(ArrayList<CurriculumModel> curriculumItems) {
    this.curriculumItems = curriculumItems;
}



@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return curriculumItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return View;
}
```

Comment: Where you are creating instance of CourseHomeFragment in your MyHomeFragment?

Comment: Which arraylist you want to pass ?

Comment: @GrlsHU. I want to pass the arraylist named models. It is populated in asynctask of the HomeFragment. but currently am subclassing the home fragment and using the models in CourseHomeFragment

Comment: @GrIsHu. I got trapped in that issue. Could u please help.

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure what you trying to achieve with that weird class structure but I can tell why models list is empty in CourseHomeFragment.

`CourseHomeFragment.onCreateView()` method overrides implementation of the `HomeFragment.onCreateView()` which is never executed.
If you decide that CourseHomeFragment will extends e.g. Fragment you pass models like this:

- in HomeFragment move `new GetData().execute("");` to `onActivityCreated()` callback (let your fragment to load view first and then populate data)
- in CourseHomeFragment implement method that takes models list and pass to adapter, remember to call notifyDataSetChanged on adapter
- in `GetData.onPostExecute` find your CourseHomeFragment and pass models list to introduced method

Most common approach in Android, regarding loading data, is letting your UI to load view first assuming that there is no data yet. Then trigger data loading in the background and when it's done pass it to UI(on main thread). I would also advice to check if your fragment is still available when onPostExecute is called. The best way to do it is:

```
private GetData getDataTask;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle bundle) {
     getDataTask = new GetData();
     getDataTask.execute("");
}

public void onDestroyView() {
    if (getDataTask != null) {
        getDataTask.cancel(false);
        getDataTask = null;
    }
}

private class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // Performing operation and updating the Arraylist models //

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        AppData.showSpinnerDialog(getActivity(), false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (isCancelled()) {
            return;
        }
        CourseHomeFragment f = (CourseHomeFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentbyTag("Tab1");
        f.setModels(models);
        AppData.dismisssSpinnerDialog();
    }
}
```

**Update:**

```
public class CourseHomeFragment extends Fragment {
   private ArrayList<CurriculumModel> curriculum = new ArrayList<CurriculumModel>();
    ListView lview;
    CourseRowAdapter mAdapter;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newcourse_screen, container, false);
    lview = (ListView) V.findViewById(R.id.listView_course);

    ((PullToRefreshListView) lview)
        .setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                // Do work to refresh the list here.
                // new GetCourses().execute("");
                ((PullToRefreshListView) lview).onRefreshComplete();
            }
        });

    mAdapter = new CourseRowAdapter(getActivity(),
        null, true);//I don't know your implementation, you have to handle this null value

    lview.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    return V;
    }

   public void setModels(List<ModelClass> models) {
       mAdapter.setModels(models);//implement this method in adapter
       mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have implemented the asynctask in onActivityCreated(). The list view is populated but not showing in first time. it is showing after switching between tabs.

Comment: If you just moved running asynctask to onActivityCreated then it's not enough. When models list is populated with some data it does not mean that fragment will automatically refresh fragment's view. You must call adapter's methods. I suggest to follow all my instructions and refactor your entire code. If you fail please paste again as much code as you can to this post.

Comment: i dono how to do the second and third step you mentioned. could u please post the code in your answer.

Comment: I removed the subclassing and implemented onActivityCreated, But cant get the second and third points. Please help.

Comment: I have added basic implementation for these 2 points. It's very easy. If this is still a challenge for you I suggest to go through some Android training with focus on adapters and loading data. If you are not afraid to spend some money I recommend this book http://commonsware.com/Android/

Comment: Great its showing listview on first load with data. but when i changed  and get back to that tab, its empty. What to do.

Comment: Could you please post your current code including implementation of CourseRowAdapter? Screenshoot would be helpful to understand what you trying to do.

Comment: I have added the adapter implementation. Asynctask is running on Activity created and showing the listview in first tab. But when i changed tab and come back to first tab, its empty.

Comment: It's because your CourseHomeFragment is recreated every time you switch(it's detached and attached again see http://developer.android.com/images/fragment_lifecycle.png)
To solve this you could override onSaveInstansceState() in CourseHomeFragment and store your list of data. Then in onCreateView() check savedInstanceState if it's not null and look for your data.